# Connect from a docker container to SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, docker, localdb, docker-network

How can I connect from a Linux container to (localdb)\msSqlLocalDB running on the host?

I have several containers that include databases and I have no problem connecting to them from my local machine.  I also have containers that connect to resources on my box using host.docker.internal.  In this case, I need to connect from the container, to SQL Server localdb running on my machine.

I'm part of a large team and the developers are using localdb.  I am introducing docker into our environment, with my new application, and it will need to connect to their existing localdb.

I know how to use host.docker.internal to reference the host, but I don't know how to connect to localDB.  I think LocalDB uses named pipes instead of a network name and I am having trouble with the connect string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't belive this is possible.

LocalDb supports only Named Pipes connections.  Connections from a Linux Docker container to a host-based resource supports only TCP/IP, and Linux Named Pipes and Windows Named Pipes are not interoperable.

Comment: Is that a problem on the side of the client driver? Just that I think it is theoretically possible to connect to a Windows pipe with Samba

Comment: Sure.  Named Pipes has run over TCP/IP for a very long time now.  So it's possible to write a TDS-over-Named Pipes client for Linux.  But localdb only listens on local named pipes, which run over shared memory, not TCP/IP.  So it would also require some docker magic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would it be possible to use `SetSecurityInfo` on the named pipe handle, perhaps from a SQLCLR module, or when running as SYSTEM, and thereby open up LocalDB to the network?

Comment: I too add a similar requirement. but it turned out there were only two options. 1. Moving the db in docker container. 2. moving the db to cloud.